# Lua pattern replacement

Tags: xml, lua, lua-patterns

Got the following XML structure:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>
<xml>
   <v id="Node_Name_1">Node_1_Value</v>
   <v id="Node_Name_2">Node_2_Value</v>
   <v id="Node_Name_3">Node_3_Value</v>
   <v id="Node_Name_4">Node_4_Value</v>
</xml>
```

The structure above is returned by a web service as String, what I want is to transform that structure into:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xml>
   <Node_Name_1>Node_1_Value</Node_Name_1>
   <Node_Name_2>Node_2_Value</Node_Name_2>
   <Node_Name_3>Node_3_Value</Node_Name_3>
   <Node_Name_4>Node_4_Value</Node_Name_4>
</xml>
```

This is my code:

```
local pattern = '(<v id="(.+)">(.+)</v>)'
local rplcmnt = "<%1>%2</%1>"
local endXml = string:gsub(orgXml, pattern, rplcmnt)
local endStr = "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><xml>"..endXml.."</xml>"
```

The problem is that the pattern returns the whole content of node  and at replacing stage it takes first node name, create the tag and then uses it for wrap everything else.

Comment: it would be better if your regex is like `'(<v id="(.+?)">(.+?)</v>)'`

Comment: Do you really want to convert UTF-16 to UTF-8 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
local pattern = '(<v id="(.-)">(.-)</v>)'
local rplcmnt = "<%2>%3</%2>"
local endXml = string.gsub(orgXml, pattern, rplcmnt)
```

The differences from your code are:

- the use of non-greedy match `.-` instead of `.+`.
- the correct replacement pattern, because everything in Lua starts at 1 instead of 0.
- the use of `string.gsub` instead of `string:gsub`.
  You could also use `orgXml:gsub(pattern, rplcmnt)`.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use regex for this. Use an xml library and/or an xsl transform.

Comment: Special XML parsers are needed only if you are expecting nested `<v ...>` tags in the document

Comment: Can you "parse" or "transform" any random tiny xml fragment without an xml parser? Possibly. Should you? Probably not.

Comment: There is no "random xml fragment" here.  XML structure tree is known beforehand.  One line of Lua code is enough to perform the task.

Comment: "Random" in the sense that it could be *any* "XML structure tree" which is "known beforehand". Not "random" as in "the xml data can be random". Like I said, you can tailor a pattern for any given (simple enough) xml tree but you shouldn't. You should use the right tools for this job because, sooner or later, you will need them.

Comment: Whether to use regex for simple xml jobs or not is kind of holywar :-)

Comment: The argument is less about using them and more about encouraging people to use them. Using them is one thing. Knowing when to use them another. Encouraging people to use them still another. Encouraging and supporting usage, especially on a site like this one, is a bad choice I believe.